# Day and month of 1980 DSM-III publication

Tags: psychiatry, history-of-psychology, dsm

I cannot for the life of me find the exact date -- day, month, year -- for the original DSM-III publication. The Google Citation, Amazon info, APA page, and others only list 1980. Does anyone know? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this present moment I cannot find full date information, but looking at [a copy of the DSM-III I have found](http://displus.sk/DSM/subory/dsm3.pdf), on the bottom of the 3rd page of the PDF it points out:

> First Printing, February 1980
>   Second Printing, May 1980

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.